# asp.net mvc3 user roles and access rights

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, roles

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application, I am having users, roles and entities. User Roles will be having access to entities. So while storing users and roles in database which of following is good approach?

1. To store user list in the entity tables
2. Entity Ids in the user table.

In future the number of entities may increase to 1000,10000 so I want to consider the performance aspect also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the relationship between Role and Entity is many- to many. One role can have zero or more entities and one Entity may belongs to zero or more Role. So create a third table to store those with 2 columns, `RoleId` and `EntityID`

**Sample data would look like**

```
ROLE_ID        ENTITY_ID
-----------------------------------
1              144
1              146
2              194
4              14
4              194
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependent upon the granularity of control you need for your application you may want to consider the model used in Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) which is now part of .NET Framework 4.5.  This is a [claims-based architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx) and the term that is used for what you are calling **Entity** is **Resource**.  What differs from your model is they also have the concept of **Operation**.  A **Resource** can have many **Operations**, and a typical **Operation** would be something like read, write, execute. This is where the finer granularity of control comes in.

So in this case an **Operation** for a particular **Resource** can have many **Roles** and a **Role** can have many **Operations**, requiring another table to map this many-to-many relationship. Use of int for a primary key in **Roles** and **Operations** as object ID's is good for performance.  **User's** can have many **Roles** and **Roles** will have many **Users**, so once again you will need another table to manage this many-to-many relationship.

So the answer to question 1 is you do not store the **User** list in a the **Entity** table. You have a separate **User** table that maps to table of **Users-To-Roles**, which maps to **Roles**, which maps to **Roles-To-Operations**, which maps to a table of **Operations**, which maps to table of **Resources**. If you do not need the granularity of **Operations** eliminate that table and map your **Roles** to **Resources** via another table to handle this many-to-many relationship.

The answer to question 2 is no, you would not have an **Entity** (**Resource**) ID in the **User** table. A **User** is mapped to a **Resource** via the relationships I have described above.

The best approach for using this model and the full extent of the claims-based architecture is to not assign **Roles** to your methods using the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which is how it was typically done in the past.  Instead assign **Resource** and **Operation** to your methods which decouples your security policy from your application. For a model of this approach look at [ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimsprincipalpermissionattribute.aspx).  You can create your own custom AuthorizeAttribute that uses this approach.